# Clean method for Pandas Dataframe to set the lowest n values in each row to zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform the values of a Pandas Dataframe so that the 3 smallest columns for instance is set to zero:

```
row1: 0.21, 0.11, 0.24, 0.52, 0.12
row2: 0.31, 0.01, 0.44, 0.52, 0.52
```

Would become:

```
row1: 0.0, 0.0, 0.24, 0.52, 0.0
row2: 0.0, 0.0. 0.0, 0.52, 0.52
```

I would preferably like to do this without some loop.

Comment: define "smallest" - what metric are you using to evaluate "smallness"

Comment: The smallest floating point value ( all columns have float values.)

Comment: I don’t understand what “3 smallest columns is set to zero” means. From the example data it looks like “all values except the 3 largest are set to zero”. But even this can’t be right because 0.31 is greater than 0.24.

Comment: Oh, I see now. When the OP says 'columns' they mean values in each row. I would have described the problem differently: "set the lowest three values in each row to zero".

Comment: @Bill thanks, I'll rephrase the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) on `axis=1`. [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with `method='min'` and `ascending=False` will establish an ordering within the row such that the smallest value is 1 and the largest is 5 (the total length of the row). We then use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace all values with rank less than 3:

```
df = df.where(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) < 3, 0)
```

We can also use the opposite condition with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to keep values that rank higher than 3 and replace those which are 3 or lower with 0:

```
df = df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) >= 3, 0)
```

Either option produces `df`:

```
     0    1     2     3     4
0  0.0  0.0  0.24  0.52  0.00
1  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.52  0.52
```

*Note depending on desired behaviour we may also want `method='dense'` or `method='first'` which will change how duplicated values are handled in the ranking.

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [0.21, 0.31],
    1: [0.11, 0.01],
    2: [0.24, 0.44],
    3: [0.52, 0.52],
    4: [0.12, 0.52]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

A - Use list(df["col"].unique()) and sort/sorted to get the first three values. Put it into a list.

B - Use df.loc to remove the rows with a value within this new list
(something like df.loc[df["col"].isin(a)] )